# Scan unmounted external USB drive for malware without Infecting the system

Tags: backup, external-hdd, malware

I have an external USB backup drive that I suspect being infected with a rootkit and fear it might spread to the host Linux system when just connected. Some experts say that some malware has infected systems from USB media even when unmounted. How can I scan and clean it safely?
Thank you

Comment: Indeed. This is possible if the "malware" is located within the boot block/partition. Ideally, you'll want a resident (TSR - in memory) AV product. But I'd be hard pressed to recommend one. That's something only *you* can determine from research based on your own security standards. :)

Comment: Why would the OS *execute* the boot block on a hot-plugged USB disk that hasn't been mounted? But a USB device that has been modified at hardware/firmware level for evil purposes might also emulate a USB *keyboard* and start blindly sending common shortcut keys for opening a terminal window, then commands after them. Anyway, if you suspect high-grade malware, don't scan infected disks with your primary computer; go to a flea market, get a cheap old computer you can easily afford to reinstall or even completely lose, and use that for scanning the disk.

Comment: The problem is that the USB stick is *unusable* if the stick cannot be plugged in. So what's the alternative? Throw it away? If the OP intends to ever use it again. The OP will want to guard against being "bitten" by anything that *may* be present on it. Hence my reply. Further reading of your reply strongly indicates yo don't understand how *infinitely* small the infections can be, or what they are capable of accomplishing. The affect can, when intended, take *years* to manifest, and are capable of a *wide* array destructive accomplishments.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM really for the insights. I have read about a rootkit - #badBios one - that infected an unmounted media. That's why I'm so afraid of dealing with my external HDD. I tried to get that resource for you but couldn't find it now.

Comment: somebody: I know the danger.. and I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: @telcoM: Here's where I got the info on unmounted media being infected by rootkits from:
https://twitter.com/dragosr/status/393022639549063168

Answer (score 0):

Disable all `udev` rules that will automatically execute something when you plug in any USB device. ("Desktop" environments in particular like to have automounters etc., but disable the rest for good measure).

Alternatively: Make a bootable USB stick with a read-only compressed file system with whatever you need to scan and clean the drive, disconnect your main harddisk from your computer, boot from the USB stick. As the system on the USB stick is compressed, it's impossible to remount it read-write, even if the rootkit should be devious enough to try.

But the probability of your USB drive being infected with a rootkit is really really low.

Comment: Thank you so much @dirkt for your input.. I'm searching and learning how to do it right now. 
However.. if you can guide me more please:
We have here three different things:
- External USB HDD has been connected, mounted, before.. on a possibly BIOS-Resident-rootkit-infected system: Will that make it infected?
If not infected: Why?
If infected:
- Same External USB HDD now connected unmounted, on a clean system: Will it infect the new system's Media or BIOS?
Much Thanks!

Comment: That entirely depends on the BIOS-resident rootkit - if the *system* has been infect (i.e., BIOS flash ROM), and it sits deep enough and bypasses the OS, it can do whatever it wants, and nothing you do in the OS will prevent it from doing so. OTOH, if it's only the harddisk that contains the BIOS-rootkit, nothing will happen as long you don't execute any files from that harddisk. So connecting and mounting it is completely safe (assuming you don't have any automation that wants to execute files on it, like Windows does).